# Bad Request Error Sending from Nodejs - Raw Message Missing header info

Tags: node.js, next.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to send an email using nodejs on a vercel host.

I am getting a bad request using the sendgrid/mail api.  It looks as though it is not creating the header info in the request to Sendgrid.

When I dump the message, is it just the json info i am sending.

Here is the code i am using.

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')

const SENDGRID_API_KEY = process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY;

export default function (req, res) {

    const mailData = {
        from: 'dhook@fullonconsulting.com',
        to: req.body.email,
        subject: 'Message to Full On Consulting',
        text: req.body.message,
        html: '<div>'+req.body.message+'</div>'
    }
    const {
      classes: {
        Mail,
      },
    } = require('@sendgrid/helpers');
    const mail = Mail.create(mailData);
    const body = mail.toJSON();
    console.log("======================================== ");
    console.log("RAW BODY: " + JSON.stringify(body));
    console.log("======================================== ");

    sendMail(mailData)
    .then((result) => {
            console.log('Email sent...', result);
            res.status(200).json({ status: 'SUCCESS' })
        })
    .catch((error) => console.log('Error ... ' + error.message));
}

async function sendMail(mailData) {
  try {

    var promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

      sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY)

      const msg = {
        to: mailData.to, // Change to your recipient
        from: mailData.from, // Change to your verified sender
        subject: mailData.subject,
        text: mailData.text,
        html: mailData.html,
      }
      console.log("API KEY: " + SENDGRID_API_KEY);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));

      sgMail
        .send(msg)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Email sent');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          console.log('RECEIVED ERROR')
        })
    });

     //promise.then( result => {
     // console.log("PRomise Success ...");
     //}, function(error) {
     // console.log("Promise Failure...");
     //});

  } catch (error) {
        console.log("CATCH ERROR: " + error)
        return error;
  }
}
```

Here is the Error

```
ResponseError: Bad Request
    at node_modules/@sendgrid/client/src/classes/client.js:146:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 400,
  response: {
    headers: {
      server: 'nginx',
      date: 'Sat, 30 Oct 2021 13:51:20 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '219',
      connection: 'close',
      'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'POST',
      'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl',
      'access-control-max-age': '600',
      'x-no-cors-reason': 'https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=600; includeSubDomains'
    },
    body: { errors: [Array] }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(error.response.body);` in your `catch` block? I can only see that it says `errors: [Array]` but it would be most useful to see what is in that array.

Answer (score 1):

I was not passing the info correctly from my front-end form which was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try expanding the `response.body` object and look for the error messages along with the help messages that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

step 1: you should verify sendgrid account setting->sender athentication ->verify single sender verification

step 2: sendgrid From Email : "verifiedemail@gmail.com"

step 3: to email && env file config